# finding a/b mod c

Tags: math

I know this may seem like a math question but i just saw this in a contest and I really want to know how to solve it.

We have

> a (mod c)

and

> b (mod c)

and we're looking for the value of the quotient

> (a/b) (mod c)

Any ideas?

Comment: This question might be a better fit for http://math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: And as a hint, `a/b` is the same as `a * (1/b)` where `(1/b)` is the [multiplicative inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) of `b` in the group Z (mod c).

Comment: This is on-topic, the solution is an algorithm to compute 1/b.

Comment: By the way, in Java, there's `BigInteger.modInverse`. You can also implement extended Euclidian algorithm yourself for instructional purposes.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In the ring of integers modulo `C`, these equations are equivalent:

> `A / B (mod C)`
>   `A * (1/B) (mod C)`
>   `A * B`<sup>-1</sup>`(mod C)`.

Thus you need to find `B`<sup>-1</sup>, the multiplicative inverse of `B` modulo `C`. You can find it using e.g. extended Euclidian algorithm.

Note that not every number has a multiplicative inverse for the given modulus.

Specifically, `B`<sup>-1</sup> exists if and only if `gcd(B, C) = 1` (i.e. `B` and `C` are coprime).

#### See also

- [Wikipedia/Modular multiplicative inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse)
- [Wikipedia/Extended Euclidian algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm)

---

#### Modular multiplicative inverse: Example

Suppose we want to find the multiplicative inverse of 3 modulo 11.

That is, we want to find

> `x = 3`<sup>-1</sup>`(mod 11)`
>   `x = 1/3 (mod 11)`
>   `3x = 1 (mod 11)`

Using extended Euclidian algorithm, you will find that:

> `x = 4 (mod 11)`

Thus, the modular multiplicative inverse of 3 modulo 11 is 4. In other words:

> `A / 3 == A * 4 (mod 11)`

---

#### Naive algorithm: brute force search

One way to solve this:

> `3x = 1 (mod 11)`

Is to simply try `x` for all values `0..11`, and see if the equation holds true. For small modulus, this algorithm may be acceptable, but extended Euclidian algorithm is much better asymptotically.

Comment: That's like me saying A-B is A+(-B)...true, but not productive.

Comment: Sorry but i just didn't understand that. can you please explain more?

Comment: @rownage It IS productive, because division is not simple in modular arithmetic.  The only way to actually perform division is to find the multiplicative inverse.  A google search for modular division wouldn't be nearly as helpful as a google search for multiplicative inverse.  Just because a property is simple for normal mathematics doesn't mean the property is even true in more elaborate situations such as this.

Comment: so it isn't (a*b^-1)(mod c), but rather a*b^-1(mod c)?

Comment: @rownage: `a * b^-1 (mod c)` is mathematical notation.  Using C-notation, that would be equivalent to `(a * inverseOfB) % c`

Comment: `B = 0 (mod C)` means `B` and `C` are not coprimes. Inverse does not exist in this case.

Comment: How to find this modulo even when modular inverse doesn't exist, because answer clearly exists, it seems we just can't find it, also, any way to do this for integer division?

Answer (score -1):

There are potentially many answers. When all you have is k = B mod C, then B could be any k+CN for all integer N.

This means B could potentially be very large. So large, in fact, to make A/B approach zero.

However, that's just one way to respond.

Comment: No, B could never be large enough to make A/B into zero. It could be very large and A/B would be extremely small but it would never actually be zero. You can say it tends to zero as B tends to infinity though so your general idea was right. I'm just a mathematician so like to be precise. :) But that observation of taking a fixed A and varying B does admirably demonstrate the fact there are multiple valid answers. Its interesting to wonder if the correct answer is meant to be a function of m,n or if it just a badly specified question... +1 overall anyway. ;-)

Comment: Eh? are you two using real numbers in an equation that specified "mod C"? In princple of course it's possible to specify a number system that works that way, but the normal convention is that you're working with integers modulo some integer, so no matter how large B is, it is also some value 0 <= n < C (the numbers represent infinite sets of integers), and while A/B will always have an integer result. Division is always defined as the inverse of multiplication, so where multiplication behaves differently (e.g. by giving a modulo C result), division behaves differently to match.

Comment: Specific example: Mod-6 arithmetic. 3/2 is undefined. Why? Nothing you can multiply by two will yield an odd number, given the even modulus. Is that what you mean? Us computer guys are used to dealing with mod-2^32 arithmetic, except that division is defined as an approximation so that |b*(a/b)| <= |a|.

Oh, and one other thing: He didn't say he was working in modular arithmetic; he said he had some numbers modulo another number. This is maybe splitting hairs, but should the presence of a modulus operation be enough to conclude that the entire problem is about modular arithmetic?

Comment: Yes, we two are using real numbers. The problem was specified in terms of formulae which include the modulus function, but the question didn't explicitly say that the variables ranged only over the integers 0 <= i <C. So, for example, in mod-6 arithmetic (which phrase clearly specifies a particular six-element field) then indeed 3/2 has no answer, but clearly (7.5 * 2) mod 6 == 3 if you treat the modulus function as being perfectly-well defined over the real numbers (as it is: A mod B == A - B*floor(A/B)).

Answer (score -6):

I think it can be written as(But not sure)

```
(a/b)%c = ((a)%(b*c))/b
```

Comment: I don't think that's correct.  Regardless, `/` changes its definition when `mod` is involved.

Comment: there is a phenomenon of inverse modulo which applies here.