# finding ((a +b)/c)mod m

Tags: algorithm, math, numbers, number-theory

I would like to calculate:

```
((a+b)/c)mod m
```

I would like to know if there is any efficient way since `a` is too big but  `b` , `c`  and `m` fit in a simple 32-bit int.

Comment: which language are you using...

Comment: .. and what do you mean by "too big"? Bigger than a 32-bit number? Can it fit 64-bit?

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3530661/180100) might help

Comment: possible duplicate of [finding a/b mod c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530643/finding-a-b-mod-c)

Comment: @NidhishKrishnan  I am using c laungauge and 'a' can be upto 10^1000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no division operator in modular arithmetic. Instead, you must calculate the modular inverse of the denominator, then multiply. Thus, in your example, you would calculate a+b modulo m, calculate the modular inverse of c modulo m, then multiply the two modulo m. The modular inverse can be found using the extended Euclidean algorithm. If you don't know how to compute the modular inverse, ask.